# Apache Add 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: apache-http-server, headers, access-control

I am running Apache on a Windows Server 2012 Machine, an keep getting No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header messages.

Specifically, the message I get is this:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://myAWSDNS.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:7070/. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin
>   'http://myAWSDNS.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com' is
>   therefore not allowed access

which I dont understand, since the requested resource and the origin are on the same domain.

Anyway, I want to enable CORS on this Apache server, so that this issue does not come up anymore, however, I am unsure how to enable it.

I have found several articles, however they are all written in a way that some knowledge of Apache seems to be assumed, and I am fairly new in Apache.

So, if anyone can point me towards how to enable CORS to get rid of above error message, in a step-by-step fasion, that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Since first URL is on port `7070` but second does not specify port, (assumed `80` then), it is not the "same" domain.

On your server's configuration files (should be something like `httpd.conf`) search for `mod_headers`: You should find a line that begins with:

```
LoadModule headers_module [...]
```

Remove the `#` in front of it if there is one to activate it.

Then, on the config of the server at `7070` add:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://myAWSDNS.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com"
```